# Eclipse RCP program with debug info

Tags: eclipse, rcp, debug-symbols

I have written an RCP program. Somewhere in my underlying plug-in there is a NullPointerException. I get the stack trace and everything, but the code doesn't seem to be generated with debug info in it because I don't get the line info:

```
at com.ktec.bla1.handler.Handler.performChangesQuery(Unknown Source)
at com.ktec.bla1.handler.Handler.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:293)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:476)
```

I have added the line

javacDebugInfo=true

to all build.properties I could find. Even the generated build.xml file in my plug-in project contains the property

<property name="javacDebugInfo" value="on"/>

but still... my code still shows up with "unknown source" in the stack trace.
Any idea is highly appreciated.

Cheers,
Kai

Answer (score 2):

I used to have the same issue, I have also tried to set javacDebugInfo=true but it did not work, I resolved it by setting compilerArg to contain debug information. For Sun JDK compiler(1.5) that was -g (check yours compiler argument for including debug information).

For Sun JDK compiler you can add this line to yours build.properties

```
compilerArg=-g
```